# extract specific column from file?

Tags: regex, linux

I've one file having records like below

```
AAA***000***LLL
BBB***111***PPP
```

Want only second column values in output file.

OutputFile

```
000
111
```

Is there any way I could do it using linux command ?

Comment: Are `*`s verbatim? Do exactly three `*`s separate the fields?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `awk`

```
awk -v FS='[*]{3}' '{print $2}' file
```

The `FS='[*]{3}'` means three `*`s will be used verbatim as field separator. Notice that setting the `FS` as `FS='***'` is wrong since the `***` is not a valid regular expression.

---

If `awk` is not available, which is highly unlikely on a Linux box, you can use GNU `sed`:

```
sed -En 's/[*]{3}/\n/; s/[*]{3}.*//; s/.*\n//p' file
```